# Find vertical position in window

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to know the vertical position of the cursor relative to the top of the window. I tried this

```
(defun cursor-line-in-window ()
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((current-line (line-number-at-pos (point)))
           (top-of-window-line (progn (move-to-window-line 0)
                          (line-number-at-pos (point)))))                                                                              
      (- current-line top-of-window-line))))
```

It works, except when I'm in an org-mode file where several lines are folded in under a headline. So I would like to either:

1: find a way to count the number of visible lines in a range, or

2: find a function that gives me the vertical position directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `(nth 6 (posn-at-point))`, which should be a pair `(COL . ROW)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a non-very-elegant solution:

```
(defun cursor-line-in-window ()
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (let ((pos (point))
          (r 0))
      (move-to-window-line 0)
      (while (<= (point) pos)
        (next-line 1)
        (beginning-of-line)
        (incf r))
      r)))
```